# How Do I Use Apache RewriteMap with PHP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been looking into using [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) to dynamically handle a range of URL rewrites, and what I'd like to do is use a PHP script to generate the appropriate rewrite conditions and rules -- but I just can't get it working.

I've got Apache running on a Linux server with WebHost Manager and cPanel.

I added the following to WHM > Apache Configuration > Include Editor > PreVirtual Host Include > All Versions:

```
RewriteMap myrules "prg:/usr/lib/php /path/to/my/script.php"
```

I updated the config file and Apache restarted okay.

Now I'd like to call the RewriteMap I defined from an .htaccess file to execute the rewrite, but this is where I'm stuck and everything seems to break.

I'd like to grab the incoming domain, check it against the map, and return the associated domain:user_name value. Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?${myrules:%{HTTP_HOST}}\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/user/${myrules:%{HTTP_HOST}}/$1 [NC,P,L]
```

So, just for example, if my map has johnsmith.com:john-smith, then the incoming URL johnsmith.com would proxy for the content at mywebsite.com/user/john-smith/.

**First, I'm pretty sure the cond/rule above is all wrong.**

Getting it correct is my first priority.

**Second, how would I output my map using the PHP script defined by the RewriteMap?**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't do this. You have the prg: example [here](http://www.kuplen.at/2009/04/mod_rewrite-with-rewritemap-external-rewriting-program/comment-page-1/), but read the comments first :)

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` is your server's host name, not the client's name. There are some [`REMOTE_*`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) variables, though I am not sure how reliable these values are.

Comment: See [prg: External Rewriting Program](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg) for an explanation with a small Perl example.

Comment: @dusan.bajic The comments there seem to suggest a redirect. Unfortunately I can't just redirect, I need to proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does johnsmith.com resolve to your server in the first place? If johnsmith.com and mywebsite.com are handled by the same server, you don't need to proxy the request.

I think your rule should be more like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mywebsite.com/user/${myrules:%1}/$0 [NC,P,L]
# or
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAPTO:${myrules:%1}]
RewriteCond %{ENV:MAPTO} !=""
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mywebsite.com/user/%{ENV:MAPTO}/$0 [NC,P,L]
```

Notes:

- `$0` is the whole string matched by the RewriteRule's pattern (if the .htaccess is in your DocumentRoot, `$0` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` are the same)
- `%1` is the string matched by the first capturing parentheses of the last RewriteCond (so, the value of the Host header without the potential prefix "www.")

On the second set of rules, the first rule put the result of the "RewriteMap call" in a environment variable called MAPTO. The second one, is intended to ignore unknown/non-mapped host (MAPTO valued to the empty string).

And an illustrating PHP code as RewriteMap:

```
<?php
$map = [
    'foo.com' => 'bar',
    'johnsmith.com' => 'john-smith',
];

if (!defined('STDOUT'))
    define('STDOUT', fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
if (!defined('STDIN'))
    define('STDIN', fopen('php://stdin', 'r'));
set_file_buffer(STDOUT, 0);
while (!feof(STDIN)) {
    $input = rtrim(fgets(STDIN), "\n");
    fputs(STDOUT, (array_key_exists($input, $map) ? $map[$input] : 'NULL') . "\n");
}
```

Note: the `'NULL'` value is the string expected by Apache to know when a value is not mapped to another one. It allows you to define your own default value at Apache's level. eg: to have "root" as fallback, use the following syntax: `${myrules:%1|root}`.

Comment: Thank you for the great examples! Could you explain what's going on in the second rule set? Also, I'd like to be able to match full hosts in my map, for example johnsmith.com or johnsmith.net or sandbox.johnsmith.org.

Comment: @HWD in deed, the domain extensions were missing in my code example to be consistent with the rules. I also edited my answer to add a few more informations.

Comment: The rewrite condition you have seems to only match .com -- what about other extensions? Wonderful help, thank you.

Comment: @HWD I kept your initial design which implied a ".com" extension. But if you want any domain to be matched, without a potential "www." prefix, you can use `^(?:www\.)?(.+)` instead.

Comment: I believe the PHP code is giving me errors. STDOUT/STDIN seem to be returning as strings instead of resources.

Comment: I guess the PHP constants aren't available. I used the long form and it worked $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

Comment: After an apache update, I'm getting "/index.html.var" appended to the end of my URL. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Any idea why this works fine when there's a string match (^.*$) but not when there isn't? For example, johnsmith.com/blog/ is working, but just johnsmith.com does not.

Comment: `^.*$` matches an empty path. And it really depends on your rules (a "conflict" with an other one?), if they are in a .htaccess, where it is, ...

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had to use *DirectoryIndex disabled* to prevent index.php from being appended to my rewrite rule when there wasn't a path. It appears to be working now.